# Shoulda matchers - delegate_method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, shoulda

I have a simple delegator class

```
class Service::Fs::Account < DelegateClass(Bank::Account)
  extend SingleForwardable

  def initialize(args={})
    @account = Bank::Account.new(args)
    super(@account)
  end

  def_delegators :"Bank::Account", :all, :create, :update
end
```

from my rails console, everything works fine

```
2.1.8 :002 > Service::Fs::Account.all
  Bank::Account Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "bank_accounts".* FROM "bank_accounts"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

This my spec for `Account` delegator class

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Service::Fs::Account do
  describe 'delegations' do
    it { should delegate_method(:all).to(Bank::Account) }
  end
end
```

tests are failing with the following error

```
 Failure/Error: it { should delegate_method(:all).to(Bank::Account) }
   Expected Service::Fs::Account to delegate #all to #Bank::Account object
   Method calls sent to Service::Fs::Account#Bank::Account: (none)
 # ./spec/models/service/fs/account_spec.rb:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

can anyone help me figure out why this test is failing? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using should matchers, you can test this behavior explicitly using RSpec mocks

```
it "delegates 'all' to Bank::Account" do
  expect(Bank::Account).to receive(:all)
  Service::Fs::Account.all
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the assertion expects a symbol. I have this working for me:

```
it { should delegate_method(:all).to(:account) }
```

Or with the new expect syntax:

```
it { is_expected.to delegate_method(:all).to(:account) }
```

See; https://thoughtbot.com/blog/shoulda-matchers-2-6-0